# Need to manage a slab of 'theoretical' memory

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, gpgpu

I need to manage memory that's in a separate memory space. Another program has a large slab of contiguous memory that my code cannot directly access, and notifies my code of its size during initialization.  The other program will ask my code to "allocate" X bytes from the slab, and will later notify my code to deallocate the allocated blocks.  The allocations and deallocations will be more or less unpredictable, much like the use of regular `malloc` and `free`.  It's up to my code to manage the dynamic memory for the other process.  The intended use has to do with device memory on a GPU, but I would rather not make the question specific to that. I'd like an answer that's generic, maybe even enough that I could theoretically use it as a back-end for a network API for managing virtual memory on a remote machine.

The basic functionality I need is to be able initialize the manager with the slab size, perform the equivalent of `malloc()` and `free()`, and get a few stats like remaining available memory and maybe maximum allocatable size.

Obviously, I can't use `malloc()` and `free()` 'abstractly'. I also don't want the management of my actual process memory to interfere with the management of my abstract slab.

What would be the best way to go about this? And, more specifically, does the standard library or Boost have this kind of a facility?

**Notes:**

- Allocation strategy is not extremely important at this point. I mean, maybe it is, but first I need to figure out how I'm going to go about this business.
- I'm going to be using this for allocating between tens and several thousand buffers per second, with different sizes; some as small as several bytes, some as large as gigabytes. There will be no buildup of allocated space over a long period of time.

Comment: Specifically, questions about programming libraries are permitted and encouraged.  However, questions about _recommending a library_ do not fit the goal of this site.  You can still get help if you pose a question that has a _single, correct answer_, such as "Can library X be used to do Y?"

Comment: I'm reading the question as "Can I implement a remote memory manager, where Computer A has a huge "slab" of memory, and asks Computer B to `malloc` from slab and return a pointer, which A writes and reads from, and when it's done, it tells Computer B `free` the pointer.  So Computer B is managing the individual allocations out of the "slab", though all the memory is actually in A's virtual memory.   A touch odd, but it makes sense.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes, basically that's it, although nobody said A is a computer. Maybe it's just a guy asking a computer to malloc and free pages of his notebook.

Comment: I recently created a system of PCs and several applications with the requirement that one PC, the controller, be used to monitor and issue commands to applications running on other PCs. The architecture uses TCP/IP servers and clients, and a custom protocol that facilitates messaging between the applications running across the network.   Could you do something similar with a _controller_ application that monitors and directs the other processes through a collection of sockets server/client connections and custom messaging?

Answer (score 0):

> a back-end for a network API for managing virtual memory on a remote machine

A networked system should not be concerned about the memory management of a remote node. The remote node should be free to choose whether to serve the request by allocating memory on the fastest but scarcest memory or in a larger but slower storage or a hybrid of both depending on its own heuristics, other requests happening concurrently, prioritization/security policy set by the network admin, and so on.

Thinking in terms of malloc and free will limit what a remote server can do to serve the requests efficiently.

Note that strictly speaking malloc itself is only managing "theoretical"/"virtual" memory. The OS kernel can page memory allocated with malloc in and out of swap space and assign or move its physical address on the MMU. The memory "address" returned by "malloc" is actually just a virtual address which doesn't correspond to actual physical address.

Unlike networked system, when managing hardware you do usually want to dictate very closely what the hardware should do on each step, because, presumably, a hardware is only connected to a single system, so any contention is only local contention, and considerations regarding performance throughput usually trumps everything else. The nature of managing remote resource on a networked system and local hardware is similar but quite different.

If you're interested in designs for networked shared memory, you might want to checkout in-memory databases (e.g. Redis) or networked file systems. A networked shared memory can usually afford to use a user-friendly string keys to point to the memory slabs; hardware shared memory usually want to keep it simple and fast by using simple numeric handles.

Both networked and hardware need to deal with splitting a single resource for multiple independent processes securely. In many popular operating system, the code responsible for managing hardware allocation is usually the kernel. It's quite rare for userspace program to be the one responsible for managing hardware on monolithic OSes. Maybe you should be writing a device driver? Many GPGPU device now have an MMU.

Certainly, there's nothing preventing you from writing a `gpu_malloc()`/`gpu_free()`. It theoretically should be possible to `mmap` the remote system's address space into the process's virtual memory address space so that programs could just use the remote memory just as any other memory.

> I'm going to be using this for allocating between tens and several thousand buffers per second, with different sizes; some as small as several bytes, some as large as gigabytes.

Generally, you don't want having thousands of small allocations. System calls that relates to memory management can be expensive if it involves remote systems, so it might be necessary to have the client program to allocate large slabs and do its own suballocation (malloc does this, small mallocs usually causes one system call to allocate larger memory than is requested and malloc then suballocates the slab).

Comment: You're assuming the remote node can manage memory. Assume that it cannot. Also, yes, `malloc()` and `free()` are managing virtual memory; but I didn't ask about managing the process' virtual memory...

Comment: As for needing to split a single hardware resource for use by multiple processes concurrently - 1. That might not always be the case, and 2. The splitting could be different than in a computer's memory, i.e. you don't have processes which need their memory space and want to allocate within it, you could be looking at GPU kernels which merely access a few buffers whose addresses they were passed. They might allocate memory in other spaces but that's not the host's concern.